# Updating subview of tableviewcell on change in corresponding tablecell textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and each `UITableViewCell` has a textfield and `UILabel`. How can I update the label string on a cell when the textfield in the corresponding cell has been edited.

I tried something like this, but it's not working

```
UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldEdited:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];    

- (void)textFieldEdited:(UITextField*)textfield event:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:
                          [[[event touchesForView:textfield] anyObject]
                           locationInView:cartTable]];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[[myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:101];
    [myLabel setText:@"44"];
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Create custom UITableViewCell class and implement your UITextField delegates method in that class. Also it benefit you will directly got access of your respective cell Label.

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean, is the method being called, are the references nil etc?

Comment: Try adding [myTable reloadInputViews]; after you set the label's text.

Comment: The app crashes when the method is called. And shows the following error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SA_MyCart touchesForView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. This may help you.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    UITableviewCell *currentCell = (UITableviewCell *) [textField superView];
    UILabel *label = [currentCell viewWithTag:YOURLABELTAG];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
    return YES;
}
```

Note: don't forget to set `textFieldDelegate` and set `label Tag`

Comment: can you tell me how i can get indexpath of that cell? 
I tried 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [cartTable indexPathForCell:currentCell];
    NSLog (@"%d",indexPath.row);

Always gives 0

Comment: I found out how to get the indexpath

 CGPoint location = [cartTable convertPoint:textField.frame.origin fromView:textField.superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [cartTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

Answer (score 0):

In your textFieldEdited: update your data source and reload the table data

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

Handle the changes then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to return the updated cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
   CGPoint location = [tableview convertPoint:yourtextfield.frame.origin fromView:yourtextfield.superview];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblItemList indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];


   UITableview *cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews) 
        {

          if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
            {

                  [(UILabel *) subView setText:@"Hearts"];

            }
        }
```

Comment: Be sure to use 

`CGPoint location = [tableview convertPoint:yourtextfield.frame.origin fromView:yourtextfield.superview.superview];`

in ios 7 as there is a change in view hierarchy in ios 7 storyboards

Answer (score 0):

for Finding indexpath of cell is simple one line code

**NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];**